# Error Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I'm trying to use signalR for chatting. While I was in the beginning steps I'm getting this error.

**ERROR:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin' or
>   one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin' or one of its dependencies.
>   The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin' could not
>   be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding
>   information was supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name:
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A partial bind
>   occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided. WRN:
>   This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly. WRN: It
>   is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the
>   assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and
>   public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Muhammad Rehan/Dropbox/WebProject - Shared/Neon/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Muhammad Rehan\Dropbox\WebProject -
>   Shared\Neon\bin Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Muhammad
>   Rehan\Dropbox\WebProject - Shared\Neon\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file: C:\Users\Muhammad
>   Rehan\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine
>   configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Muhammad
>   Rehan/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/d1746cd6/ea89ef06/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Muhammad
>   Rehan/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/d1746cd6/ea89ef06/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Muhammad
>   Rehan/Dropbox/WebProject -
>   Shared/Neon/bin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DLL. LOG: Using
>   application configuration file: C:\Users\Muhammad
>   Rehan\Dropbox\WebProject - Shared\Neon\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file: C:\Users\Muhammad
>   Rehan\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine
>   configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 ERR:
>   Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070057). Probing
>   terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +16    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +217    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +170
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930508 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212

Comment: What is the question? Also provide some more information about problem

Comment: updated. That I'm stuck in this error. This is my first experience with signalR for chatting.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` has nothing to do with SignalR.  It may have something to do with the fact that it's a `.Net 4.5` assembly and you are compiling your application in `.Net 4.0.30319`.

Comment: If that's the case. Please mention how to compile with .Net 4.5?